# Hundreds of build errors running code in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Having this issue when I run my code and I get like 450 build errors when trying to run the code.

This program is for a univerisy coursework so I was mainly working on it from my computer in my room but I went to uni to ask some questions, got my code from github, tried running and that's when I got all those erros. I asked the teacher and he said that's it probably because the windows or VS versions are different but all I had to do was right-click on the project and press "Retarget solution". It worked.

But I'm back home and I did the retarget solution, but for some reason it doesn't seem to be doing anything and I'm getting all these errors.[Error list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z1tMW.png)

Here's a few of those errors copied if it helps having them in text. These aren't classes in my project. I assume they're c++ standard libraries or classes.

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)  E1696   cannot open source file "errno.h"   Coursework  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\include\cerrno  7   
Error (active)  E1696   cannot open source file "float.h"   Coursework  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\include\cfloat  7   
Error (active)  E1696   cannot open source file "corecrt.h" Coursework  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\include\crtdefs.h   10  
Error (active)  E1696   cannot open source file "stddef.h"  Coursework  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\include\cstddef 7   
Error (active)  E1696   cannot open source file "stdio.h"   Coursework  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\include\cstdio  8   
Error (active)  E1696   cannot open source file "stdlib.h"  Coursework  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\include\cstdlib 8   
Error (active)  E1696   cannot open source file "math.h"    Coursework  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\include\cstdlib 9   
Error (active)  E0282   the global scope has no "acosf" Coursework  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\include\cmath   27  
Error (active)  E0282   the global scope has no "acoshf"    Coursework  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\include\cmath   32  
Error (active)  E0282   the global scope has no "asinf" Coursework  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\include\cmath   37  
Error (active)  E0282   the global scope has no "asinhf"    Coursework  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\include\cmath   42  
Error (active)  E0282   the global scope has no "atanf" Coursework  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\include\cmath   47  
Error (active)  E0282   the global scope has no "atanhf"    Coursework  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\include\cmath   52  
Error (active)  E0282   the global scope has no "atan2f"    Coursework  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\include\cmath   57  
Error (active)  E0282   the global scope has no "cbrtf" Coursework  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\include\cmath   62  
Error (active)  E0282   the global scope has no "ceilf" Coursework  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\include\cmath   67  
Error (active)  E0282   the global scope has no "copysignf" Coursework  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\include\cmath   73  
Error (active)  E0282   the global scope has no "cosf"  Coursework  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\include\cmath   78  
Error (active)  E0282   the global scope has no "coshf" Coursework  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\include\cmath   83  
Error (active)  E0282   the global scope has no "erff"  Coursework  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\include\cmath   88
```

Comment: Check the windows sdk version setting of your project.

Comment: BTW, It's better to copy the errors from the Output Tab.

Comment: There's a newer version of VS2017 available too. I doubt the version at uni is updated to that but you'll never now.

Comment: Done, I pasted some of the errors. It's my first time asking a question here so idk if there's a more efficient way of doing it.

I don't know about uni, but I try to keep VS up to date on my home computer. But isn't that what "retarget solution" is for? To make sure the code works on the version of VS it's in? At least that's what the teacher told me.

Comment: It looks more like your installation is borked than a target mismatch.

Comment: So my computer just blue screened because a cable in my pc got misplaced and stopped the gpu fan. Anyways, after rebooting my pc and opening the project again it seems to work fine again, no errors.

Comment: Perhaps link to the project on github. My VS is newer so that may say other thing.

Answer (score 0):

So it wasn't really that big of a problem. All I had to do was do is "retarget solution". Close VS and then reopen the solution from the local repo. I tried the same thing in some of my friend's computers and I had to do the same thing.

Either way, problem "solved."